# Upload Image via URL

Tags: php, image, upload

**Code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['update_avatar'])) {
    $url = $_POST['avatar'];
    $info = getimagesize($url);

    if(isset($info['name'])) {
        echo "Exists";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

How can I avoid getting PHP errors when the user types an invalid URL, random piece of text or invalid image URL etc?

Comment: Have a look at this answer maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-check-if-file-exists-from-web-address-url-in-php

Comment: Removed thanks noise

Answer (score 0):

If there's an error, `getimagesize` returns `false`, so test for that. And to suppress error messages from a function, put `@` before it:

```
$info = @getimagesize($url);
if (!$info) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    // Process the image
}
```

Comment: I still get the following error either way: Warning: getimagesize(www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <folder>/<script>.php on line <line_number>

Comment: You can use the `@` prefix to suppress error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use exception handling. Place your critical code into a try..catch block. You can find more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: I still get the following error either way: Warning: getimagesize(www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <folder>/<script>.php on line <line_number>