# PHP File checking always returning false

Tags: php

This bit of code reads from an RSS feed and shoulfd detect if an image exisists on the server or not:

```
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://www.goapr.com/news/category/product-release/feed/';
$sxml = @simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
if($sxml){
    $i=0;
    foreach($sxml->channel as $channel){
        foreach($channel->item as $item){
            //if($i==6){break;}
            if($item->prodimg=="~"){break;}
            if($item->prodpage=="~"){break;}
            $i += 1;

            $file = 'http://www.goapr.co.uk'. $item->prodimg; 

            if (file_exists($file)) {
            echo "The file $file exists";
            } else {
            echo "The file $file does not exist";
            }

        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'Sorry there was an error. The recent products will return shortly.';
}
?>
```

Many of the images do exist, but it returns all images not found:

The file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/ultras4.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/30tpulleys.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/tiguan.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/2325row.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/plus.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/2017r.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/v24gti.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/q5gen3.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/includes/img/newprod/s8downpipes.png does not existThe file http://www.goapr.co.uk/products/
All images are detected as not found.

Its not the same as: [How to check if a file exists from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url) as the files are on the same filesystem as this PHP page.

Comment: file_exists only works on the local filesystem. I personally use cURL to open a connection and get the info and check if the response is 404, though checking if `fopen` succeeds usually is enough.

Comment: Hi Thanks. These files are on the same file system as this PHP page, does this help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How check if file exists from the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-check-if-file-exists-from-the-url)

Comment: You need to check them by their local path and not URL then e.g. `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."path/to/pictures/"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check if a file on the local filesystem exists you should refer to it via it's local path and not its URL, something like:

```
$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path/to/images/".$item->prodimg;
```

Note that the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is the root path as set up by the webserver host (which means it may not work in the commandline.

You can also use `__DIR__."/".$item->prodimg` if the images are in the same directory as the currently running script.