# php getimagesize check if image exist

Tags: php, getimagesize

I am using following

```
if ($dataprev['imagefile']!='' && getimagesize('http://localhost/branches/standard/uploads/' . $dataprev['imagefile']) !== false) {
    $html .= '&nbsp;<img src="http://localhost/branches/standard/uploads/' . $dataprev['imagefile'] . '" height="100" border="0"/>';
}
```

To check if image exist. For some reason it doesnt work well. The app tries to load some unexisting images. What is the problem and how to do it better?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: it is inside tcpdf. Error is TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: xxx.jpg But becouse he does not find image. I checked it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url/29714882#29714882

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is still the same.