# Cannot check file_exist for external url in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a file exists or not in external url.

(My external url is another project's file in my local directory)

The other project folder is **mvf**. So I'm trying to get it like:

```
    $url = '//localhost/mvf/assets/img/img.png';
```

I want to check if this file exists or not for the path above. My code is:

```
    if(file_exists($url)) {
       echo "exist";
    } else {
       echo "no";
    }
```

But the above code always returns **no** eventhough the file exits.

Comment: try with `absolute` path

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url/29714882

Comment: It they are on the same server, can't you just check it through the file system instead of through a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,`absolute path`

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'mvf/assets/img/img.png';
//please change this path according to your folder system
if(file_exists($url)) {
   echo "exist";
} else {
   echo "no";
}
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is giving current project url

Comment: are you using any PHP framework? did you try comment section's links