# How to check if a file exists in a url in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

```
@if (file_exists(env('BASE_URL_MASTER').$p->main_image))

<img class="primary-img" src="{{env('BASE_URL_MASTER').$p->main_image}}" alt="single-product" height="200px" width="400px">

@else
<img class="primary-img" src="{{asset($p->main_image?$p->main_image:'')}}" alt="single-product" height="200px" width="400px">
endif
```

I want to check whether given URL has Image if image is available then `@if` condition should work. but its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a file exists from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684771/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-from-a-url)

Comment: yes but its not working in my case i want to use in blade

Answer (score 1):

Using `file_get_content()` instead.
Example: 
`$file = file_get_content('url_to_file or path_to_file');
if (strlen($file) > 0) 'file exist...'`